# Chamar uma função dentro da outra, através de uma string

Tags: javascript, eval

Para facilitar o trabalho dos demais programadores da empresa <strike>cujo padrão é não ter padrão</strike>, eu criei um biblioteca em JavaScript com algumas funções de formatação e validação de campos de formulário (data, telefone, CPF, CNPJ, etc.).

Ao final do processo, essa biblioteca me permitiu uma chamada muito simples:

```
<input type="[data|telefone|...]" name="" value="">
```

No final do carregamento da página eu gero uma *NodeList* e atribuo as devidas funções para cada `input` de acordo com o seu `type`.

O tal código então ficou assim: **[JSBin.com](http://jsbin.com/neluno/1/watch?js,output)**

O problema com o método utilizado é que, apesar de apenas uma das funções estar sendo executa para cada `input` (como deve ser), eu estou setando **TODAS** as funções para cada objeto encontrado na minha *NodeList*. Ou seja, para cada objeto eu fico com um código quilométrico, contendo várias funções que esse objeto **nunca** irá utilizar.

Em páginas normais, aonde esse recurso não é muito utilizado, o problema é totalmente imperceptível. No entanto, em páginas aonde essas funções são chamadas inúmeras vezes, é possível notar uma certa perda de desempenho após o loading da página.
E, uma vez que o sistema da empresa é para ser utilizado também em aparelhos móveis, uma pequena perda de desempenho pode acabar se tornando um grande problema.

Para solucionar isso, eu pensei em isolar cada uma das funções. Aqui está o meu problema!
Eu tenho N funções (*data, telefone, cpf, ...*), dentro de uma função global (*setEvents*) e tudo o que eu tenho para chamar essas funções internas é o nome delas em forma de **string**.

Eu já tentei de várias maneiras, mas não obtive sucesso.
A única forma que funcionou até agora foi utilizando o `eval`. Mas, como diz o **JS Bin**: "*eval is evil.*"

Comment: Qual é a ideia por trás de `[função a ser chamada]`? isso é passado para dentro de `a()` ou de onde vem?

Comment: @Sergio Eu determino qual será a função a ser chamada através de um `this.getAttribute("type")` e chamo uma função diferente para cada resultado encontrado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Só uma sugestão, você pode colocar as funções dentro de um objeto, e chamar a mesma pelo nome:

```
<script>
  function a() {
    var nomeDaFuncao = [função a ser chamada];

    var fncObj = {
        b: function(objeto) {
         . . .
        }

        c: function(objeto) {
         . . .
        }
    }

    fncObj[nomeDaFuncao](objeto);
  }
</script>
```

Mas seria muito melhor se você explicar o motivo para esta lógica estranha... pois mesmo da forma que eu falei, me soa meio estranho ter algo desse tipo... será que um `switch` não resolveria?

Comment: Eu estou criando uma biblioteca com funções de formatação e validação de campos. No caso, para fazer a chama da função de data, por exemplo, basta colocar `<input type="data">`. Agora estou querendo melhorar a chamada para reduzir o processamento no carregamento da página. Então pensei em separar em funções específicas. Mas estou tendo esse problema na hora de fazer a chamada de cada uma das funções.

Comment: Segundo o que andei lendo, um switch seria a forma mais rápida. De qualquer forma, não existe diferença perceptível nos tempos, então o ideal seria se preocupar mais com a legibilidade do que com a performance neste caso.

Comment: O `switch` é o meu plano B. Como eu já tenho que fazer a declaração dos nomes das funções em um evento *onLoad*, eu estou tentando ter que fazer outra vez dentro da função global. Mas, se não tiver como, é o que eu vou fazer. Eu acabei de editar o meu post para explicar melhor o meu problema. Talvez isso ajude em uma solução. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Olá, tente fazer assim:

```
function a(){
    alert('olá a');
    var nomeFuncao = 'b';
    var b = function(){
        alert('olá b');
    };

    var c = function(){
        alert('olá c');
    };

    eval(nomeFuncao)();
}
```

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/yoqoxupi/1/)

Você pode também usar esta alternativa sem `eval()`:

```
func_a = function(arg1) {
    alert('call a '+ arg1);
};
func_b = function() {
    alert('b');
};
func_c = function() {
    alert('c');
};

var n = "a";

 window["func_" + n]('arg1');
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5SvSG/1/)

Outra opção usando Jquery:

```
$.main = {
    a : function(arg){
        alert('function a - arg: '+arg);
    },
    b : function(){
        alert('b');
    },
    c : function(){
        alert('c');
    },
    call : function(func,arg){
        $.main[func](arg);
    }
};
$.main.call('a','param 1');
$.main.call('b');
$.main.call('c');
```

[Com Jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/X4g7F/)

Comment: Desculpa, mas eu não consegui entender muito bem a sua solução. Você apenas transformou as funções em variáveis e continuou usando o `eval` para chama-las. E é justamente o `eval` que eu quero eliminar.

Comment: Ok, veja uma alternativa sem eval();

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar um `namespace` para isto. Um objecto com várias funções onde chama a função que precisa e não polui o espaço global como na sua ideia original.

```
var validar = {

    date: function (value) {
        return [value, 'Função para data'];
    },
    text: function (value) {
        return [value, 'Função para texto'];
    },
    password: function (value) {
        return [value, 'Função para passwords'];
    }
}
```

E depois pode usar assim:

```
// "el" no exemplo é o elemento que quer analisar
var type = el.getAttribute("type");
var retornoFuncao = validar[type](el.value);
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/vqpNc/)

Eu usei o mesmo código dentro de cada função mas imagino que queria adaptar essa parte.

Answer (score 1):

Tente adicionar sua funções explicitamente no objeto `window` como [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/n2D2n/):

```
window.dyna = function(param) {
    alert("dyna " + param);
}
window["dyna"]("oi");
```

Alguns navegadores isso nem é necessário e funcionaria da maneira como você fez.

**Edit 1**

Testando aqui não funciona no seu exemplo por que as funções `b()` e `c()` não estão diretamente no objeto `window`. Sendo assim não são encontradas no escopo de `window`

Já que elas são criadas no escopo da function `a()`, sendo que elas só vão existir dentro da function `a()`, e se dentro de `a()` você quiser acessar `b()`, por exemplo, você tem que fazer algo assim:

```
this["b"]();
// que é o mesmo que this.b();
```

**Edit 2**

Para utilizar o `this`, como citei você tem fazer algo parecido com isso, seu problema é de escopo, então você tem que anexar sua função em um objeto que seja acessível no escopo onde você pretende chama-la, no caso o `this`, como segue no código de exemplo:

```
function a(nomeDaFuncao) {

  // anexa a function "b" ao objeto local this
  this.b  = function(param) {
      alert("b " + param);
  }

  // anexa a function "c" ao objeto local this
  this.c = function(param) {
      alert("c " + param);
  }

  // chama a function pelo nome no objeto local this
  this[nomeDaFuncao]("oi");
}

a(nomeDaFuncao);
```

Exemplo [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/wMvTh/)

Para compreender um pouco melhor como funciona o escopo dos objetos no [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), recomendo [esse](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/) link que é muito bom e [esse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) do [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

> Obs: Não sei qual seu real problema para precisar de uma solução desse tipo, mais dependendo qual for, pode haver maneiras mais simples e limpas de fazer, mais está solução irá funcionar para sua questão atual.

Comment: @Márcio, se você ler a pergunta, talvez você veja que é exatamente isso que ele procura, uma alternativa para chamar um método pelo nome (`string`), no escopo escopo especifico. Se você entende um pouco de [tag:javascript] sabe que `eval`, também não é nada "legal".

Comment: Eu já tentei utilizar `this[nomeDaFuncao](objeto);` mas também não funcionou. Segundo o depurador "_this[nomeDaFuncao] is not a function_"

Comment: @JúlioPradera, veja se minha solução atualizada, lhe auxilia em algo.

Comment: @Márcio, sempre vi em todos os lugares que eval(), não foi criado para executar scripts dinâmicos, através de strings, eval para mim e outros [colegas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) é a pior das ideias, enquanto window[], também não é das [melhores](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294262/difference-between-window-and-eval-javascript), mais é a "menos pior" ao meu entendimento, no entanto você tem todo o direito de discordar. E detalhe, não me apego a reputação.

Comment: @Fernando as duas respostas que eu citei não usam eval, usam outra forma, exatamente porque não gosto de eval nem de acessar o window. E não coloquei o link por causa da rep, mas sim da tag que tenho alguns míseros potinhos. De qualquer for, boa sorte aí usando window ;)

Comment: @Fernando A sua nova solução funciona, mas é ela que eu estou utilizando e tentando mudar. :D / Eu achei que esse seria um problema simples, e por isso acabei não me explicando muito bem. Acabo de editar o post para lhes mostrar o meu real problema. Ficaria muito grato se você pudesse ler. E obrigado pela ajuda.